# Какой метод вызывается при смене activity?

Tags: java, android, activity

Опишу ситуацию: есть главное activity A и поверх него запускается другое activity B. Позже activity B закрывается, и появляется activity A. Так вот, при появлении activity A вызывается ли какой-либо метод? Дайте, пожалуйста, его название, если таковой имеется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывается метод `onStart()` первого активити.

> При вызове onStart() окно еще не видно пользователю, но вскоре будет
>   видно. Вызывается непосредственно перед тем, как активность становится
>   видимой пользователю. Сопровождается вызовом метода onResume(), если
>   активность получает передний план, или вызовом метода onStop(), если
>   становится скрытой.